# VB Script to remove a row from an excel file if it contains a particular data

Tags: vbscript

I need to create a VB script that will remove a particular row from an excel file if that row contains a particular data separated by '/'. For example if a row contains data as 'NSV/PL' or 'OI/HJK' then that row should be deleted from the file, and if that row contains data as 'GHJ' and no data with '/' then that row should be present in the file.

This can be further understood by the below example:

```
Date    Market  Done     Office     Type    Contract    Cost    Expiry   Total  MW  Comments

04-Jul-16   SFE FGH  Q316   CAP TERA    $4.25       $300.00 10  
04-Jul-16   SFE FGH  Q316   CAP TERA    $4.25       $300.00 1   
04-Jul-16   SFE WERE     Q118   DEVC    TERA            $60.00  7   
04-Jul-16   SFE WERE     Q218   DEVC    TERA            $54.30  5   
04-Jul-16   SFE WERE/VIC IR  Q416   DEVC    TERA            $13.00  15  
04-Jul-16   SFE YUP  Q318   DEVC    TERA            $55.35  5   
04-Jul-16   SFE YUP  Q316   ASIAN PUT   TERA    $0.65       $50.00  25
```

Please help me soon.

Comment: A good strategy for doing this is to first write a VBA macro which does what you want and then change it to a VBScript program (which is usually a mechanical process). What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I can't write a VBA Macro as that would be a different process, I just need ascript which will automatically remove e.g. "04-Jul-16   SFE WERE/VIC IR  Q416   DEVC    TERA            $13.00  15" from the file. That WERE/VIC can be different but that '/' will be same and it can be any row.

Comment: VBScript and VBA are virtually the same language. The only difference is that with VBA you can do things like declare worksheet variables and use intellisense to make sure you are using the Excel object model correctly. Once this works, it usually takes about 5 minutes to switch the early-bound VBA objects to late-bound VBScript objects. There is a lot on the web about how to make VBA macros run as VBScript scripts. But -- if you want to go all VBScript you can do so. What have you tried?

Comment: Sounds like a good script. Let us know how it goes. Did you have a question?

Comment: I have not tried the VBA script, was going for the VB Script.

Comment: Using VBScript, try to start with the following steps: instantiate `Excel.Application`, open the file, put the target range into array, process array within loop to identify target rows, delete the rows, save the workbook. Going step by step in case of any issues - add the code you ran to your question and describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This

```
excelfile = "Excel File Path Here" ' Example : C:\Documents\ExcelFile.xlsx
excelSheetName = "Sheet1"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set book = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelfile)
Set sheet = book.Sheets(excelSheetName)

cols = sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
i = 1
Do While i <= sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    j = 1
    Do While j<= cols
        If InStr(sheet.Cells(i,j).Value,"/") > 0 Then
            sheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            i = i - 1
            Exit Do
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop
book.Save
book.Close True
objExcel.Quit
MsgBox "Task Complete", vbOKOnly, "Remove Excel Rows"
```